# Webpack with html fragments

Tags: webpack

How would you configure webpack when index.html has html fragments?  Say for example the header and the footer are fragments that get injected into index (ie.:  `<div w3-include-html='header.html'></div>`).

My current approach is copying the fragments int the public folder using:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     filename: 'header.html',
     template: './header.html'
 })
```

and keeping `<div w3-include-html='header.html'></div>` in index.html.

Is there a better way of dealing with html fragments?

Cheers.